# Encountering fatal memory error, having issues

Tags: javascript, angular

I am doing some data analysis. This is the code, the data is kind of long so I shortened it:

```
const distance = 500

var check = [
    [3,2,53,1.4735804398854573],
    [3,2,51,1.0832286377747853],
    [3,2,160,1.5322645571496754]
]

var true_speeds =[
    1.390336678624153,
    1.0664809250831604,
    1.6724854636192323,
    1.465806443810463,
    1.289532861709595,
    1.1171281540393831,
    1.777853966693878,
    1.2035294610261917,
    1.2333490034341812,
    1.1561777402162552
]

var true_ttg = []
for(var i=0; i<true_speeds.length; i++){
    true_ttg.push(distance/true_speeds[i])
}

var checker = 0;
var deviation = []
var bypass = false

function speedFinals(){
    for(var i=0; i<check.length; i){
        if(i%10 == 1){
            if(bypass){
                checker++
            }
            else{
                bypass = true
            }
        }
        var current_ttg = distance/check[i][3]
        deviation.push([(true_ttg[checker]-current_ttg)/current_ttg*100])
    }
    return(deviation)
}
console.log(speedFinals())
```

Now, I am just running this in sublime. It has no affiliation to the original Ionic project I got this data from. I started getting a memory error out of nowhere, this is the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7E96351EF napi_wrap+114271
 2: 00007FF7E95DFE66 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66630
 3: 00007FF7E95E0C66 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70214
 4: 00007FF7E9DF522E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7E9DDD301 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF7E9CA983C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF7E9CB4A70 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF7E9CB1594 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF7E9CA6D93 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF7E9CA5404 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2452
11: 00007FF7E9CC660D v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+61
12: 00007FF7E9A2CB2F v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1295
13: 00007FF7EA24978D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637
14: 000002EFA900549E
```

I am using: `node v12.18.1`
What do I do?

Comment: your heap memory is getting overflowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are push elements in array indefinitely. Because the loop is running forever.

`deviation.push([(true_ttg[checker]-current_ttg)/current_ttg*100])`

Try to execute this code and check.

```
const distance = 500

var check = [
    [3,2,53,1.4735804398854573],
    [3,2,51,1.0832286377747853],
    [3,2,160,1.5322645571496754]
]

var true_speeds =[
    1.390336678624153,
    1.0664809250831604,
    1.6724854636192323,
    1.465806443810463,
    1.289532861709595,
    1.1171281540393831,
    1.777853966693878,
    1.2035294610261917,
    1.2333490034341812,
    1.1561777402162552
]

var true_ttg = []
for(var i=0; i<true_speeds.length; i++){
    true_ttg.push(distance/true_speeds[i])
}

var checker = 0;
var deviation = []
var bypass = false

function speedFinals(){
    for(var i=0; i<check.length; i++){
        if(i%10 == 1){
            if(bypass){
                checker++
            }
            else{
                bypass = true
            }
        }
        var current_ttg = distance/check[i][3]
        deviation.push([(true_ttg[checker]-current_ttg)/current_ttg*100])
    }
    return(deviation)
}
console.log(speedFinals())
```

Comment: hahahah wow I forgot to add ++ to the i in the for loop. Wow.